# cURL - Server suddenly responds with Status Code 500 - Why?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to read some data from my website using cURL. Todo this I am running about 50-60 requests per minute to my server. At about 30 requests it seems that the script stopped working but I figured out that I suddenly get an Status code 500 back from my curl requests.

The routine is nothing special it increases the actual day of the month until it reaches the end of the month. For each day I read something (not part of this code).

The following code shows how I make the cURL requests. After 30 requests it sends me 500 back, but when I try it then again without the loop and only get the 31 request it is fine, so it only does not work with my mass requests.

Any ideas where the problem might be?

Thanks!

```
            // To get an ASP.NET SessionID I first visit the page as usual...
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mypage.de/mysite.aspx");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    $o = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    //start the request
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mypage.de/mysite.aspx");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length' => '999'));

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);


    $headers = array();
    //$headers[] = "Referer: http://www.mypage.de/mysite.aspx";
    //$headers[] = "Content-Length: 999";

    $data = "somevalidpostdata";

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $o = curl_exec($c);
    $status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo "\r\n" . $status . "\r\n";
    curl_close($c);
```

Thanks,
WorldSignia

Comment: Perhaps some flood protection? Or you're actually overloading the server.

Comment: I don't think so, because I can just stop the script and rerun it and I will get my results immediately but only again the first 30 requests

Answer (score 3):

500 means **Internal Server Error**.

Maybe you are sending the requests too fast.
Try adding `usleep(500000);` between the requets.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP500 means something went wrong on the server while processing the request.  You will need to see what the error is on http://www.mypage.de/mysite.aspx.  Is there a message or payload property that you can inspect?  It may contain the error being thrown by the application.

It's unclear to me if you control the application that your script is connecting too?  If not, and you are just scraping a page, then you should definitely introduce a sleep of a few seconds before each request or else threat management gateway applications will block your script (because it is basically a Denial of Service attack). Also you should be checking for and respecting the existence of [Robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) on the target website.

Comment: rhhh I solved it.

It has absolutely nothing todo with cURL.
To build my parameteres I had an string like this:

123:123,456,789|123:123,456,789

I split it by the | sign and then by the , sign. unfortunately the string which is hardcoded had a new line after the | sign, so like this:

123:123,456,789|
123:123,456,789

This unfortunately caused the problem that it was not split correctly and the parameteres where incorrect.

Thanks,
WorldSignia